# What is the different between Update(Object obj, Object id) and Update(string entity, Object obj) in nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm newbier in NHibernate. So, I want to update single element in database using Isession in NHibernate framwork.

I don't know What is the different between Update(Object obj, Object id) and Update(string entity, Object obj) in nhibernate?

Does anyone know that? Or Another way to update element into db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as described in [ISession.cs](https://github.com/juanplopes/nhibernate/blob/master/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/ISession.cs#L374):

```
/// <summary>
/// Update the persistent state associated with the given identifier.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// An exception is thrown if there is a persistent instance with the same identifier
/// in the current session.
/// </remarks>
/// <param name="obj">A transient instance containing updated state</param>
/// <param name="id">Identifier of persistent instance</param>
void Update(object obj, object id);

/// <summary>
/// Update the persistent instance with the identifier of the given detached
/// instance.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="entityName">The Entity name.</param>
/// <param name="obj">a detached instance containing updated state </param>
/// <remarks>
/// If there is a persistent instance with the same identifier,
/// an exception is thrown. This operation cascades to associated instances
/// if the association is mapped with <tt>cascade="save-update"</tt>.
/// </remarks>
void Update(string entityName, object obj);
```

And maybe also [Update(obj)](https://github.com/juanplopes/nhibernate/blob/master/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/ISession.cs#L364):

```
/// <summary>
/// Update the persistent instance with the identifier of the given transient instance.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// If there is a persistent instance with the same identifier, an exception is thrown. If
/// the given transient instance has a <see langword="null" /> identifier, an exception will be thrown.
/// </remarks>
/// <param name="obj">A transient instance containing updated state</param>
void Update(object obj);
```

The first case is about updating the row with provided ID with a state of the `obj`. It's ID is not so important

The second, expects, that the object was not loaded by this session. The `entityName` helps to find out correct persister (entity related hbm.xml mapping)

Finally the simple `Update(obj)` is almost as the first, but the id is resolved from the passed `obj`

In general, if we **load any Entity with the session, you do not have to call `Update()` - just Flush()**. Update helps to explicitly say: may instance is exsiting. The most preferred way is to call `SaveOrUdpate(obj)` see

[9.4.2. Updating detached objects](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-updating-detached)